# Laravel 4 relationship sort one-to-many count eager loading

Tags: php, laravel, count, one-to-many, eloquent

No sure if this is possible. I can sort everything inside the current table artists(title, body etc) but haven't figured out sorting it to tables related to it. I want to sort the artist based on how total number of songs he/she has DESC, ASC.

**How can I dynamically sort the total number of songs from the artists?**

admin/artists?sortby=songs&order=asc

[Screenshot](http://oi59.tinypic.com/av5yye.jpg)

My tables

artists: id, name, body, slug

songs: id, title, body, slug, hits, artist_id

Before this I used eager loading in the controller, Artist::with('songs)...
and then in the view I could use in the foreach loop, count($artist->songs) for the the total songs. And then I found a cleaner way 
http://laravel.io/forum/05-03-2014-eloquent-get-count-relation

Artist model

```
public function songs()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('Song');
    }

public function songsCountRelation()
{
    return $this->hasOne('Song')->selectRaw('artist_id, count("id") as count')->groupBy('artist_id');
}

public function getSongsCountAttribute()
{
    return $this->songsCountRelation->count;
}
```

Song model

```
public function artist()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('Artist');
}
```

Controller

```
public function index()
{
    // Sortby and order variables from url 
    $this->data['sortby'] = Input::get('sortby');
    $this->data['order'] = Input::get('order');

    // If the sortby and order exists in url, fetch the data and order it accordingly
    if ($this->data['sortby'] && $this->data['order'])
    {
        // Order the data based on keys from url
        $this->data['artists'] = Artist::with('songsCountRelation')->orderBy($this->data['sortby'], $this->data['order'])->get(['id', 'name', 'body', 'slug']);

    }
    else
    {
        $this->data['artists'] = Artist::with('songsCountRelation')->get(['id', 'name', 'body', 'slug']);
    }

    $this->layout->content = View::make('admin.artists.index', $this->data);
}
```

Index view

```
<th>
    {{--Sort by slug--}}
    @if ($sortby == 'slug' && $order == 'asc')

        {{ link_to_route('admin.artists.index', 'Slug', ['sortby' => 'slug', 'order' => 'desc']) }}
    @else
        {{ link_to_route('admin.artists.index', 'Slug', ['sortby' => 'slug', 'order' => 'asc']) }}
    @endif
</th>
<th>
    {{--Sort by total songs--}}
    @if ($sortby == 'songs' && $order == 'asc')
        {{ link_to_route('admin.artists.index', 'Songs', ['sortby' => 'songs', 'order' => 'desc']) }}
    @else
        {{ link_to_route('admin.artists.index', 'Songs', ['sortby' => 'songs', 'order' => 'asc']) }}
    @endif
</th>
...¨
@foreach($artists as $artist)
    <tr>
...
        <td>{{ $artist->songsCount; }}</td>
...     
    </tr>

@endforeach
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to join the tables.

```
Artist::join('songs', ...)
  ->orderByRaw('count(songs.*) asc')
  ->select('artists.*')
  ->get();
```

Comment: Thanks for guiding me to the right direction. Ending up with the code in the controller.  `$this->data['artists'] = DB::table('artists')  
->join('songs', 'artists.id', '=', 'songs.artist_id')
   ->select(DB::raw('artists.*, count(*) as songs'))
   ->groupBy('artists.id')
   ->orderBy($this->data['sortby'], $this->data['order'])
            ->get();`